# Set up FTP access to /var/www and /home/pi: (cannot upload)

Tags: tutorial

I want a quick and dirty way to upload files to /var/www and /home/pi via FTP.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md) to set up FTP access to /home/pi/FTP using pure-ftp.

But how should I then set up a new "virtual ftp user" (as described in the tutorial) so I can upload to /var/www and /home/pi?

I have set up lighttpd to serve pages from /var/www, which works fine. Doing "ls -la" in /var shows that /var/www is owned by user and group "www-data".

So I thought the following should work:

First, make a virtual user "www" for pure-ftp, which will give access to /var/www:

```
sudo pure-pw useradd www -u ftpuser -g www-data -d /var/www -m
```

Second, add the user "ftpuser" to the "www-data" group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ftpuser
```

The result is that via FTP I can view files in /var/www, but uploading folders or files doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? I've missed out the chown command that was used in the tutorial, but if I did that then lighttpd would not have access to /var/www?

Comment: I sometimes wonder what gets into the Foundation. That tutorial will probably work, but if you want to change it it needs an understanding of Linux, which would be better asked elsewhere - http://unix.stackexchange.com/ If all you want to do is transfer files, you can login as user `pi` using SFTP with NO additional programs. If you have some SPECIAL reason for not using user `pi` clarify your question.

Comment: This is what goldilocks would call an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) . You have a problem and are asking us about your assumed solution. You should ask about your actual problem - which I assume is how can users (which) upload files to directories (which).